# JavaScript Error Messages in Formvalidation

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, error-messaging

I am having difficulties with deleting the custom error messages in my form validation. Each time I submit the form, the messages replicates and I dont know how I can delete them if a field is valid. I am pleased to hear your answers!

```
form.onsubmit = function valCheck(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var fields = ev.target
  console.log(fields);

  var nameVal = /^[a-zA-ZäÄüÜöÖáàiìíéèóòúù `´,.'-]+$/;
  var emailVal = /[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+/;

  for (var i = 0; i < formLen; i++) {
    var errorText = document.createElement('P');
    div[i].appendChild(errorText);
    console.log(errorText);

    if (fields[i].value === "") {
        errorText.innerHTML = "This field should not be empty"
    }
    else if (fields[i].type == "text") {
      if (!fields[i].value.match(nameVal)) {
        errorText.innerHTML = "no numbers allowed"
      }
    }
    else if (fields[i].type == "email") {
      if (!fields[i].value.match(emailVal)) {
        errorText.innerHTML  = "insert a valid adress"
      }
    }
    else if (fields[i].type == "checkbox") {
      if (!fields[i].checked) {
        errorText.innerHTML = "checkbox need to be checked"
      }
    }
    else if (fields[i].type == "radio") {
      if (fields[i].checked) {
        errorText.innerHTML = "you need to select something"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Each time you go through this it creates and appends a new P element. You could try checking to see if you have a P element before adding it, then if you do already have one, use that instead of appending another new one.

Comment: could you tell me how this would possibly look like? i tried it, but either no message was displayed or it did not work at all.

Comment: You could just do something simple like give the element an id when you create it, but before you create it check with the document.getElementByID to see if it exists. So something like var errTextField = document.getElementByID('errorText'); if (errTextField) {errTextField.innerHTML ="Hello, World!"} else {var errorText = document.createElement('P'); ..... as you currently create it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may just to assign empty value to `errorText.innerHTML` before validation:

```
form.onsubmit = function valCheck(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  errorText.innerHTML = '';

  // setting non-empty errorText.innerHTML if form is not valid
  // ...
}
```

Comment: i specified the errorText inside the for loop, so js can't detect it if i write it where you suggested, do you know any solution for that?